Как для компилятора выглядит ссылочная переменная (ссылка)? С++
Здравствуйте многоуважаемые господа! Все мы знаем, что ссылку отличает от указателя тот факт, что мы не можем обратиться к её собственному адресу, а только к тому, чей адрес ссылке был присвоен.
Из этого назревает вопрос, а как тогда ссылка выглядит для компилятора, если у неё нет собственного адреса. В это сложно поверить поскольку у всех сущностей языка должен быть какой-либо адрес потому что, создавать в памяти что-либо и не мочь к этому обратиться в последующем - абсурдно. Каковая природа ссылки с технической точки зрения?
Моё предположение, что ссылка это какая особая сущность которая работает как якорь,поэтому она не занимает места в памяти и не имеет собственного адреса, а просто прямо отсылает на тот адрес который в неё вложили.

Указатель не обязательно имеет собственный адрес, он может быть как lvalue, так и нет.

как тогда ссылка выглядит для компилятора, если у неё нет собственного адреса. Если правила языка не позволяют взять адрес ссылки, то это ещё не значит, что для компилятора у ссылки нет адреса. Компилятор запросто может реализовать ссылку через указатель. Просто разыменовывая его автоматически где нужно, и при взятии адреса возвращать не адрес этого скрытого указателя, а адрес объекта, на который он указывает.

Ну, как уже сказали, просто как указатель с автоматическим разыменованием, где надо... Но я о "у всех сущностей языка должен быть какой-либо адрес" — какой адрес у пятерки в выражении типа int a = 5 + b;?...

Ссылка всегда реализована как указатель, если компилятор не соптимизирует ее в ничего (что он мог бы сделать и с указателем, по идее). Запрет на взятие адреса - искусственный, чтобы было легче оптимизировать.
